# Short-circuit protection, reverse polarity automotive

Tags: short-circuit, over-voltage-protection, undervoltage

I am designing a power circuit and would like to integrate the ic [VN5160S](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/vn5160s-e.pdf) to protect it, but I have doubts about the position of it.
Would the ic [VN5160S](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/vn5160s-e.pdf) be before the DC / DC converter in my circuit?
I am feeding a microcontroller, canbus, bluetooth and rf.
[image]

the power input is 12v and passes DC / DC [converter](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/ld1117.pdf) to 5v and 3.3v.

The circuit I did is correct for me or something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want it before the DC-DC converters.  Your schematic looks correct to me.

Comment: I am confused, this [datasheet](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/application_note/3d/a1/c3/a0/fc/65/46/81/CD00004389.pdf/files/CD00004389.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00004389.pdf) page 13 shows that the power is only connected to the vcc line, output is output to resistors and not output power.

Comment: @alex That figure is using the resistors to show you the loads.  From your posted question and schematic, I have no idea how you have your other circuitry connected.  The situation in the app note may not even apply to you.  This might need to be a separate question.

Comment: For my circuit, my schematics are correct then?

Comment: Yes, assuming you are doing something with the input pin.